# How to change value based on previous and future value row-wise by group

Tags: r, dplyr

**Problem:** I am trying to use `dplyr` or `ave` to do the following:

By group ID, if x1 at a given time period is 0 and the previous (t-1) and future (t+1) values equal 1, fill x1 with 1.

```
     ID = c("1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","3","3","3")
     time = c("1","2","3","4","5","1","2","3","4","1","2","3")
     x1 = as.integer(c("0","1","0","1","1","0","0","0","0","1","0","1"))
     df = data.frame(ID,time,x1)
```

**Data:**

```
  ID time x1 
  1    1  0 
  1    2  1 
  1    3  0 
  1    4  1 
  1    5  1 
  2    1  0 
  2    2  0 
  2    3  0 
  2    4  0 
  3    1  1 
  3    2  0 
  3    3  1
```

**Output I am trying to obtain:**

```
  ID time x1 
  1    1  0  
  1    2  1  
  1    3  1  
  1    4  1  
  1    5  1  
  2    1  0  
  2    2  0  
  2    3  0  
  2    4  0  
  3    1  1  
  3    2  1  
  3    3  1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
group_by(id) %>%
mutate(x1 = ifelse(lead(x1) == 1 & lag(x1) == 1 & x1 == 0, 1, x1))
```

You can just group by the id and use logic with `lead` and `lag` functions from `dplyr` to fill in the 1.